# [High Scool/College DE]Synchronization of metronomes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not sure about the level of Discipline, since i'm from a country that does education differently than US. Basicly i'm working on an assignment that requires me to learn something that isn't in our curriculum, and i've chosen the subject of synchronizing metronomes explained by differential equations. Now i've only been taught differential calculus and not DE's, but i've worked a bit on this assignment and think i have a basic grasp on things. This problem is a bit hard to explain so please bear with me. Now my problem is that i have found and somehow understood an equation explaining the synchronization here, ( http://www.math.pitt.edu/~bard/classes/mth3380/syncpapers/metronome.pdf ) on page 2 and 3.

My goal is to somehow plot the base (x) movement,to see how it changes over time but i cant figure out how to properly isolate x (or it's derivative) and still account for both metronomes and the coupling that happens.

I know this seems really confusing, and it isnt a simple problem, and thats probably a combination of english not being my native language, and not really grasping DE on more than the most basic level, but i'm stuck and cant really continue with this assignment until i get this problem solved.

If you could help me with this i would be forever grateful because you took the time to read this wall of text and some of the article i linked.
Thank you.